# How to get files in Google Drive SDK starting from particular record?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using Google's latest Drive API to pull the files list with python.If I have 100 files and I set 'maxResults' parameter to 10 then to fetch all the records I will fire 10 different request, this is fine.Now I need to fecth the records like 51-60 or 61-70, How can I get this records directly, without fetching the previous records.